# Manwha/Webtoon Where Woman Shares Body with a Dragon and Goes Back in Time

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

I am looking for a webcomic where a woman shares a body with dragon. At the beginning of the story, she is pregnant with her child and has a loving husband. However the effects of sharing a body with a dragon (or dark beast?) is starting to negatively effect her emotions. Her actions are becoming more violent and erratic and she is at risk of losing the pregnancy.

Something happens and she goes back in time.

I vaguely remember MC having long dark hair if that helps.

Comment: Any idea if she goes back in time because she died? Do you remember anything about her husband, or how far back in time she goes? Does going back in time 'cure' her from sharing a body with this dragon/other creature?